# multi processing using ctyhon

Tags: pyqt5, multiprocessing, cython

Basically, I have a GUI app built using pyqt5 and I am using cython for other stuff.

The goal here is that, when I click on a button from pyqt5 app a new process should be created calling a cython function or I don't want my pyqt5 GUI app to have impact because of the code in foo() function.

I tried:
**GuiApp.pyx**

```
def onbtnClicked(self):
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(self.signaller,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This gives me a pickeling error as below:

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <cyfunction __Pyx_CFunc_int____object___to_py..wrap at 0x00000159BAC0C2B0>: import of module 'cfunc.to_py' failed

**otherFuncs.pyx**

```
cdef int foo(signaller):
    file = open("hello.txt", "w")
    file.write("Multi threading started")
    file.close()
    # alot of things that the code cannot be pasted
    # call functions that does I.e disassembly, pefile stuff
    return 0
```

I also tried to use a pool as below:

```
def onbtnClicked(self):
    self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    self.pool.apply_async(func=foo, args=(self.signaller,))
```

The pool doesn't pop any errors and looking at task manager, I can see that a new sub process is created but I don't think it run the foo() function because `hello.txt` file doesn't seem to be created.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be certain because this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I'd guess that `foo` is a `cdef` function.

When you try to pass it as an argument then Cython creates a Python-object wrapper function for it. It's this wrapper that can't be pickled.

If you declare `foo` as a regular `def` function there's a reasonable chance it'll work (because it's a Python object accessible by attribute lookup, so can be pickled by just storing its name).

`self.signaller` is also a problem. You say in the comments that it's a `QObject`. `QObject`s have a lot of state (including signal/slot connections to other `QObject`s), and this cannot easily be pickled. *Note that this is not a Cython problem - it would not work in Python either.*

I don't think you can use multiprocessing with your application at all.

Comment: signaller is a python class as `class Signaller(QObject):` and being assigned to signaller as `self.signaller = Signaller()`

Comment: Then possibly the issue is with `foo` instead? Who knows...

Comment: the issue do seem to be with signaller. I create a new python def function and it worked fine, but as soon as I passed signaller, I got `cannot pickle 'Signaller' object`

Comment: Multiprocessing on Windows relies heavily on pickling things to transfer them between processes. I'd think it'd be hard to pickle a QObject because you'd lose all its signal-slot connections